# Perl interpreter supporting both oracle and sybase

Tags: oracle, perl, sybase, dbi

Can some one  let me know how to use both sybase functions and oracle functions in same perl script using a perl interpreter supporting both syb and ora modules?

I have 2 perl interpreter running in same machine currently.

Sybase package is build on below version of perl. I could see that version in the  README file of sybase modues

```
 bash-4.1$ /usr/bin/perl -v
 This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread.
```

I am able to use this interpreter in script and compile  successfully when I use sybase supported functions to fetch from db*

1st interpreter
test1.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

2nd perl interpretor came with oracle sdk package.
its supporting only oracle fucntions to interact with Db

```
bash-4.1$ /home/oracle/12.2.0/client_1/perl/bin/perl -v
This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi->this is supporting only oracle*
```

test2.pl

```
#!/home/oracle/12.2.0/client_1/perl/bin/perl
```

I tried to include oracle modules from this path `/home/oracle/12.2.0/client_1/perl/bin/perl` while running a script using perl bin from `/usr/bin/perl` path and `@INC` file i pointed to `/home/oracle/12.2.0/client_1/perl/DBD/Oracle.pm` it will throw error.

So I found oracle build on 1 perl version can't be included with other version of perl

test3.pl

```
#!/home/oracle/12.2.0/client_1/perl/bin/perl

---sydth/(EXEC.....)
```

Can I have  1 perl interpretor version supporting both Sybase and Oracle functions?

I am not talking about the DBI module to connect to to oracle and sybase.

I meant functions used using database handlers to support oracle and sybase after connection.

---

I managed to follow the below steps

1. Downloaded DBD-Oracle-1.73_01.tar.gz and tried to install got erros. So downloaded and installed  the below dependencies first

2.downloanded dependencies ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.4 and ExtUtils-ParseXS-35.tar.gz

3. downloaded a oracle sdk package 12.2.0 . it has perl.jdk,plsql,sqlplus.. etc
   oracle/12.2.0/client_1/perl
4. set ORACLE_HOME =/oracle/12.2.0/client_1 and LD_LIBARRY_PATH=oracle/12.2.0/client_1/perl
5. cd DBD-Oracle-1.73_01/
   --execute using perl v5.10 (perl Makefile.PL)

make && make install -> this step is throwing lot of errors

I am assuming oracle driver module and along with oracle sdk clients , can there be any kind of version mismatch here ?

### Glance of errors

```
racle.c:2379: error: âcvâ undeclared (first use in this function)

Oracle.c:2380: error: âitemsâ undeclared (first use in this function)

Oracle.c:2382: error: âXS_VERSION_BOOTCHECKâ undeclared (first use in this function)

Oracle.c:2388: warning: implicit declaration of function âPerl_newXSâ
Oracle.c:2388: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle_constantâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2389: error: âXSANYâ undeclared (first use in this function)

Oracle.c:2518: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle_ORA_OCIâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2519: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle_ora_env_varâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2523: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle__dr_dbixs_revisionâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2533: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle__db__loginâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2534: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle__db_selectall_arrayrefâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2535: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle__db_selectrow_arrayrefâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2545: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle__db_commitâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2546: error: âXS_DBD__Oracle__db_rollbackâ undeclared (first use in t heis function)

./Oracle.xsi:19: warning: implicit declaration of function âSvIVXâ
./Oracle.xsi:19: warning: implicit declaration of function âperl_get_svâ
./Oracle.xsi:19: error: lvalue required as unary â&â operand
./Oracle.xsi:19: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
./Oracle.xsi:19: error: âdbistate_tâ has no member named âcheck_versionâ
./Oracle.xsi:21: warning: implicit declaration of function âsv_setivâ
./Oracle.xsi:21: error: âGV_ADDMULTIâ undeclared (first use in this function)
./Oracle.xsi:24: warning: implicit declaration of function âora_initâ
Oracle.c:2649: error: âXSRETURN_YESâ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2367: warning: unused variable âPerl___notusedâ
make: *** [Oracle.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Given that the two Perl installations are not the same version, trying to use compiled modules from one in the other is unlikely to work. The solution is to 'just' install the DBD::Sybase module or the DBD::Oracle module using the other Perl. However that assumes you have a compiler installed, the development headers files for the Sybase/Oracle libraries, and the appropriate environment setup (LD_*PATH variables sometimes are needed). It is certainly possible but there will be some pain on the journey.

Comment: Thanks Grant. But how to find which DBD:sybase module i should download and from where and steps to install

Comment: @Poorvi make sure cpanminus is installed, then run `cpanm DBD::Sybase DBD::Oracle`

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to talk to Sybase databases is using Perl's [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) (database interface) module and [DBD::Sybase](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Sybase) (which is the database driver for Sybase). Similarly, for an Oracle database, you'd use DBI together with [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle).

It is perfectly possible to have both of these modules installed in the same Perl installation. It probably makes most sense to add DBD::Oracle to the version of Perl in `/usr/bin/perl`. You can do that by running

```
$ sudo cpan DBD::Oracle
```

on your command line. Note that you will need `sudo` access on the system and it will also need a C compiler and the Oracle development libraries.

If you have problems when you try it, post details of the errors you get in a new question here and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Thanks Dave i tried installed ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.46 and  set path export PERL5LIB=/home/**/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.46/blib/lib/ 
bash-4.1$ export ORACLE_HOME=/home/***/oracle/12.2.0/client_1
bash-4.1$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/**/oracle/12.2.0/client_1/lib.and tried to build DBD-Oracle-1.73_01 $ perl Makefile.PL 
Using DBI 1.609 (for perl 5.010001 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.010001 on linux (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Comment: above issue i fixed by installing ExtUtils-ParseXS-35.tar.gz